# WSP not working in another server

Tags: error, web, visual

My WSP is working fine on my server, but when I deploy it on another server it shows error, and no control is working.

I have created a Visual web part in SharePoint 2013 and deployed it on SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 2):

The way that visual web parts were implemented changed in SharePoint 2013. Previously, visual web parts could use an .ascx file located in the 14 hive, while in 2013 the .ascx file was embedded in the .dll and no file was deployed to the file system. This enabled visual web parts to be used in a sandboxed scenario.

So your 2013 wsp is probably failing on 2010 because it is one of the new style web parts. You can confirm this by looking in the .ascx file and seeing if the assembly references are all for version 15.0.0.0.

If this is the case, you'll need to rebuild your visual web part in the old style. It shouldn't be too hard to convert, it'll basically be a case of moving your .ascx to a mapped CONTROLTEMPLATES folder and loading that file in CreateChildControls. Here's a worked example:

http://geekswithblogs.net/gotchas/archive/2009/12/28/sharepoint-2010-creating-a-visual-webpart.aspx

Good luck! :)